# Using UIViewPropertyAnimator with repeat and autoreverse options

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewpropertyanimator

I went over every existing similar question here and couldn't find a solution.

I'm trying to do the following property animation that should autoreverse and repeat until an event happens, and then I'll stop it:

```
lookupButtonAnimator = 
UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.6,
                                               delay: 0,
                                               options: [.curveEaseIn, .autoreverse, .repeat]) {
                self.lookupButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)   
            }
```

The compiler ignores the `.autoreverse` and `.repeat` options, and only performs the animation once.

What did work for me, though, is adding the following two lines inside the animation closure:

```
                UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float.infinity)
                UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
```

However, Xcode does not like this, and presents two warnings:

> 'setAnimationRepeatCount' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the block-based animation API instead
> 'setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the block-based animation API instead

Is there any possible way to autoreverse and repeat a property animation without having to use deprecated code?

Please do not suggest to use `UIView.animate(..)` instead of `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.